# Get json data from php and use it in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, parsing

It is my first time using JSON. I am trying to get JSON data from a php script using ajax.But i am getting this error **"Error.Parsing JSON Request failed" "undefined"**.Help me this is my php script **test.php**

```
    $data='{
  "one": "One",
 "two": "Two",
 "three": "Three"
   }';

 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($data);
```

and here i am getting the data **getdata.php**

```
    var sURL = 'http://www.example.com/test.php';   

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
                            url:sURL,
                            dataType:"jsonp",
                            crossDomain:true,
                            data: {transid:trans_id , bookingdate: dateVal, bookingtime: timeVal, People: peopleVal,affiliateid: affiliate },
                            async: false,
                            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data){
                                                                                    var result = JSON.parse(data);
                                            alert(result);
                                            },
                                            error: function (x, e) {

        if (x.status == 0) {
            alert(x.response);
            alert(x + " " + e);
            alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
        }
        else if (x.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested URL not found.');
        }
        else if (x.status == 500) {
            alert('Internel Server Error.');
        }
        else if (e == 'parsererror') {

            alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.' + e.statusText);
            alert(x.response);
        } else if (e == 'timeout') {
            alert('Request Time out.');
        } else {
            alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
        }
    }

                            });
```

This is my first question so excuse any mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `jsonp`, add callback function as below

```
var sURL = 'http://www.example.com/test.php';   

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
                            url:sURL,
                            dataType:"jsonp",
                            jsonp : "callback",
                            jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
                            crossDomain:true,
                            data: {transid:trans_id , bookingdate: dateVal, bookingtime: timeVal, People: peopleVal,affiliateid: affiliate },
                            async: false,
                            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data){
                                                                                    var result = JSON.parse(data);
                                            alert(result);
                                            },
                                            error: function (x, e) {

        if (x.status == 0) {
            alert(x.response);
            alert(x + " " + e);
            alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
        }
        else if (x.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested URL not found.');
        }
        else if (x.status == 500) {
            alert('Internel Server Error.');
        }
        else if (e == 'parsererror') {

            alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.' + e.statusText);
            alert(x.response);
        } else if (e == 'timeout') {
            alert('Request Time out.');
        } else {
            alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
        }
    }

 });

function jsonpcallback(rtndata) {
  alert(rtndata.one);
}
```

In PHP make `$data as array` and then use `json_encode()` with return callback.

```
 $data=array(
  "one"=>"One",
  "two"=>"Two",
  "three"=>"Three"
 );
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($data) . ')';
```

Comment: didnt help.now fire bug is also giving a error of SyntaxError: invalid label
[Break On This Error]  
{"one":"One","two":"Two","three":"Three"}(line 1, col 1)

Comment: @KaranTuteja: try myanswer combined with this answer, it should work as json_encode method accepts array only..!!

Comment: now its giving this error in firebug SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]  

var result = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: are you sure want to get json from cross-domain ?

Comment: @gbd yes i need cross domain it is very important for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
     dataType:"jsonp",
```

to

```
dataType:"json",
```

Comment: tried it didnt help. it doesn't effect anything anyways jsonp is used for cross domain.

Comment: what do you mean by crossdomain(on same proxy)? or from external source?